# How to load a 2nd java class from a main class

Tags: java

I compiled Hello.java class file that is created Hello.class extension file.
I want to call **java.class** file from another class file like below -

```
public class Jtest{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hello h = new Hello();         //It is showing error
        System.out.println(h);
    }
}

public class  Hello{

   public String toString(){

        System.out.println("This is Hello encrypted class file.");
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You're missing a closing curly bracket.

Comment: You have to add the `Hello.class` to the classpath in order to have the `JTest` working.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I have to write classpath

Comment: Hello.class and JTest.java class files is in same folder.

Comment: Put both files into the same directory, then it will work.

Comment: I want to call Hello.class not Hello.java file.

Comment: What does encryption have to do with this?

Comment: @Md.ModasserHossain, What does "calling" a class or class file mean and what is `java.class`?

Comment: To me it seems you either need to put both classes in the same package or put both on the classpath when you run the main class.

Comment: The *.java files are the source code, when you compile (not encrypt) the java source code you produce one or more *.class files, which contain the byte code executed by the JVM.  I would strongly suggest reading the Java tutorials that will explain all of this and more - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Comment: did you forget to `return` something?

Answer (score 1):

`toString` should `return` a String, not print. The way you have it won't even compile

```
public String toString(){

    return "This is Hello encrypted class file.";
}
```